# Getting internal curve from external

Tags: matlab, math

I have a external curve with best fitted polynomial of degree n , shown in red (see top) with following parameters. x=1,0.02,0.04,...1.6 m

```
 Linear model Poly7:
 fitresult(x) = p1*x^7 + p2*x^6 + p3*x^5 + p4*x^4 + p5*x^3 + 
                p6*x^2 + p7*x + p8
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   p1 =      0.2904  (0.1959, 0.385)
   p2 =      -48.81  (-64.73, -32.89)
   p3 =        3515  (2367, 4664)
   p4 =  -1.406e+05  (-1.866e+05, -9.459e+04)
   p5 =   3.374e+06  (2.268e+06, 4.481e+06)
   p6 =  -4.858e+07  (-6.454e+07, -3.262e+07)
   p7 =   3.885e+08  (2.606e+08, 5.164e+08)
   p8 =  -1.331e+09  (-1.77e+09, -8.923e+08)
```

[image]

**Is there any function to  get internal curve ( 8 cm lower and shown in yellow) programmatically and without measuing it manually**. I have measured it manually and got the following values of the  parameters.

```
fitresult(x) = p1*x^7 + p2*x^6 + p3*x^5 + p4*x^4 + p5*x^3 + 
                    p6*x^2 + p7*x + p8
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       p1 =      0.5445  (0.4419, 0.647)
       p2 =      -91.54  (-108.8, -74.29)
       p3 =        6595  (5351, 7840)
       p4 =   -2.64e+05  (-3.138e+05, -2.141e+05)
       p5 =   6.338e+06  (5.14e+06, 7.536e+06)
       p6 =   -9.13e+07  (-1.086e+08, -7.402e+07)
       p7 =   7.305e+08  (5.921e+08, 8.689e+08)
       p8 =  -2.505e+09  (-2.98e+09, -2.03e+09)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the derivative for the external curve using `polyder`. It will give you the slope of the curve in each point. Then using `atan` you'll get the acccording angle alpha. Knowing alpha it's easy to calculate the coordinate shift for each data point.

Perhaps you need to avoid some special cases, but I think the idea should generally work.

Here is an example:

```
% shift distance
d = -0.08; 

% original curve
x = 0:0.05:2; 
y = sin(x);

% fit for the original curve
p = polyfit(x,y,7)
fitresult = polyval(p,x);

% derivative coefficients of the fit
p_der = polyder(p);

% reconstructed derivative
fitresult_der = polyval(p_der,x);

% slope in each point
alpha = -atan(fitresult_der);

% shift in x and y according to the slope
dx = d*sin(alpha);
dy = d*cos(alpha);

% shifted curve
x_prime = x + dx;
y_prime = y + dy;

% fit for the shifted curve
p_prime = polyfit(x_prime,y_prime,7)

fitresult_prime = polyval(p_prime,x_prime);

%plots
figure;
plot(x, fitresult, 'o-');
hold on;
plot(x_prime, fitresult_prime, 'o-');

for i=1:numel(x)
    plot([x(i) x_prime(i)], [fitresult(i) fitresult_prime(i)], 'k-');
end

hold off;
grid on;
legend('original', 'shift');
axis equal;
```

Parameters for the original and shifted curves:

```
p =

   -0.0001   -0.0004    0.0091   -0.0008   -0.1663   -0.0001    1.0000   -0.0000


p_prime =

   -0.0007    0.0071   -0.0160    0.0293   -0.1910    0.0372    0.9970   -0.1130
```

The result:
[image]